# Ionic 4 FCM onNotification not being called

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using [cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated](https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated) to receive push notifications, but the `this.fcm.onNotification` observable isn't being executed. I can see in the Xcode console that the message is being received, and stepping through the code I can see `-(void) notifyOfMessage:(NSData *)payload` is being called from within `FCMPlugin.m` but I can't identify why `this.fcm.onNotification` isn't being called.

I can see `FCMPlugin.js: is created` and `FCMPlugin Ready OK` in the console, and a few lines lower I can see a console.log I added to confirm that `this.platform.ready` is being called (which is where I'm subscribing to `fcm.onNotification` from within `app.component.ts`)

It's worth noting that when the app is closed or paused I receive the notifications, it's just when the app is in the foreground I can't capture when a notification is received to alert the user, and when tapping on the notification I can't read `wasTapped` property to redirect the user to a specific page (because `onNotification` isn't being triggered).

Anyone have any idea as to the cause of the problem?

I'm using:

```
@Ionic/angular: ^4.11.4
cordova-android: ^8.1.0
cordova-ios: ^5.0.1
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated: ^4.1.0
FCM_CORE_VERSION: 16.0.9
FCM_VERSION: 18.0.0,
GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION: 3.5.0,
GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION: 4.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out dreadful workaround that is satisfactory for my current needs, but doesn't entirely solve the issue at hand.

For iOS, rather than putting the following code in the `app.component.ts` `constructor`:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => { 
    // Do stuff here
  });
});
```

I put the following code within `this.initializeApp()`:

```
async this.initializeApp() {

  try { 

    let isReady = await this.platform.ready();

    if (isReady) {

      if (this.platform.is('ios') === true) {

        this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => { 
          // Do stuff
        });

      }

    }

  } catch (err) {

    // Deal with error

  }

  // Do other app init stuff

}
```

It makes no sense to me why `await` would work rather than `this.platform.ready().then()`, but for whatever reason the above works for iOS.

To get `onNotification` to work for Android, I needed to put the following in the `app.component.ts` `constructor`:

```
if (this.platform.is('android') === true) {

  this.platform.ready().then(() => {

    setTimeout(() => {

      this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => { 
        // Do stuff here
      });

    }, 100);

  });

}
```

Again, I have not idea why this is the case. But after spending days on this issue this is what I've come up with as a passable solution.

There is an issue with the above Android code though. The `onNotification` observable will only fire when the app is in the foreground. When it's closed, or paused, and you receive a notification and tap on it, the `onNotification` observable won't be fired. :(

Comment: You are subscribing to notification event multiple times, that should not be the case, even if it works, could this code create other issues?